# May cookies be disabled on apache2 server?

Tags: php, cookies, apache2

I have created and tested my code on localhost apache2 server. Then I've tried to move it on external apache2 server and cookies that worked on localhost are not appearing on external server. 
Any ideas where can be the problem?

btw i'm using `setcookie()` function like that:

```
setcookie(name, "value", time() + 5000, "/");
```

Comment: Your cookies Expire time is set to 1.3 minutes.

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with the code so far.

Comment: but I am asking, why the cookie doesn't even appear? is it a short Expire time?

Comment: is there anything I can configurate on apache2 server, to enable cookies?

Comment: Cookies should be enabled by default.

Comment: How do you Retrieve the cookies value?

Comment: I don't see them in  Google chrome develpment kid under Resources - Cookies, and in the code I get them $_COOKIE['name']. But it's not a problem, because it all worked on localhost, but not on external server. that's the problem I need to deal with. Any other ideas?